# How to enable / disable vibrate in an iPhone through an own app?

Tags: ios, iphone

I know that Apple is using an own SDK, for which most things are not migrated to the public API's. However, I still need to ask:

Can I disable or enable the ringtone, or put the iphone into "no disturbing" mode, by using an own app? I did a quick search on Google and did not find much.

What functions can I use? What are my permissions in this regard?

Useful url's are more then welcome ;)

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to change such settings.

Comment: So there's no way for me to set the iphone to "silent mode" from an app?